# How can I use variables from bash in url curl command?

Tags: python, bash, variables, curl, url

I trigger python script in bash shell.The results of python script is number. I need this number as variable in bash and I want to use it to url in curl command.

Here are exemplary data but I want to explain what I mean:

```bash
POST=$(python3 /repo/post.py)
echo "${POST}"
echo "curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json""
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json"
```

output:

```
30
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/30/?format=json"
<h1>Server error</h1>
<p>An unspecified error occured.</p>
```

But when I write manually this number I mean:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/30/?format=json"
```

I get right output

Comment: What is the output of `python /repo/post.py | od`?

Comment: Are the quotes escaped actually escaped like this in this line?  `echo "curl -H \"Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken\" \"https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json\""`

Comment: @CtrlZ Markdown wasn't displaying the new line  until my edit.

Comment: Is there anything in your web server's error log for the "500 Server Error"?

Comment: Can you add `--verbose` to the curl arguments in the command that is returning the server error so that you can see exactly what curl is requesting?

Comment: after using flag --verbose:
< HTTP/2 500                               **<-- on this step all start to fail**
< date: Wed, 14 Feb 2024 15:01:55 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 59
< x-content-type-options: nosniff

Comment: Have you tried setting the `POST` value to a static number? like `POST=30` or `POST="30"`, if by using this method it is working then you can narrow the error down to the python script.

Comment: @ArslanSohailBano If I set the POST=30 or POST="30" curl command is running in right way

Comment: Then we might need to check the output of the python script, could you run the command that @oguzismail mentioned: `python /repo/post.py | od` and compare it's content with `echo 30 | od`. Could mean that there is a sort of special character.

Comment: @ArslanSohailBano if I run these commands, output is the same for a both.  But I wonder because I run this curl command on Jenkins where whole script is writing in the bash. But this python script which I trigger, it uses json file which obtained from earlier command curl . And if I trigger Jenkins job using my repo (where json file is saved on my repo) this curl command `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ExampleToken" "https://wikipedia.org/api/post/${POST}/?format=json"` is working but if I save this json file on Jenkins workspace then this curl command is not working.

Comment: Maybe I do something wrong in Jenkins configuration?